# Use the testing image version with ReadTheDocs build system

Tags: python, python-sphinx, read-the-docs, autodoc

I'm using sphinx autodoc and the ReadTheDocs build system to build references for my application, and some libraries (actually PySide6) need libc6 >= 2.28 but the default image used by ReadTheDocs build system runs under Ubuntu 18.04 that is shipped with libc6 2.27.

I saw that there is a `testing` image available that runs on Ubuntu 20.04 (see https://github.com/readthedocs/readthedocs-docker-images) but when I change the parameter `image` to `testing` in the `.readthedocs.yaml` (as defined in https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config-file/v2.html#build) the container always run on Ubuntu 18.04 (when the container updates the apt list, it hits the bionic repo).

Is there a way to use an Ubuntu 20.04 image while building documentation using the ReadTheDocs build system?

Comment: Did you read this? https://github.com/readthedocs/readthedocs-docker-images/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.rst#testing-locally

Comment: Ah, I see, according to the `Releases` subsection of what you sent, it seems that RTD is using the latest release, and since the latest release is `7.0.7` ([release page](https://github.com/readthedocs/readthedocs-docker-images/releases)), the `testing` image is not yet available in the RTD build system. I'll switch to GitHub pages, it is more flexible.